# Casting system.array to object in c#

Tags: c#, casting

my function has the following signature

```cs
function myfunction(ref object)
```

I use it as such

```cs
 Array arr = Array.CreateInstance(System.Type.GetType("System.String"), 2);
  arr.SetValue("1", 0);

  myfunction( ref arr);
```

And I am getting

> "cannot convert from 'ref System.Array' to 'ref object'"

I was under the impression that System.Array is object ...so why am I getting this error? Is object different from Object?

Comment: Out of morbid curiosity, what does myfunction() do?

Comment: All arrays are object, but not all objects are arrays, which is also necessary to do the requested `ref` conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of 'ref object' as "I take a reference to a variable that can store an Object".  Suppose that 'myfunction' tried to store an 'int' to the variable you passed?  This would fail at runtime, which is undesirable.

On a side note, you can use typeof(string) in place of calling GetType("System.String").  You can also just say:

```
Object arr = new string[2];
```

---

To access the array first, you can do this:

```
string[] arr = new string[2];
arr[0] = "1";
object arrObj = arr;
myfunction(ref arrObj);
```

I would double check that you're using the method myfunction correctly; it's a rather unusual parameter type for taking an initialized array.

Comment: I can't do something like this arr[0] = "value" , so I can't populate it. The error i get is "cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type object

Comment: @sarsnake, if arrObj is null after calling the method, then it's happening inside myfunction; you'll need to debug what it's doing that causes it to set the reference to null.

Comment: unfortunately, i didn't write the function and I have to use it as is. So yes, it is weird and yes, it's used correctly.

Comment: actually, it's not null, my bad.

Answer (score 5):

The problem you're having is that while an array is an object, an object is not an array, so in your function, if your array could be passed in as a ref object, the array could be assigned anything that is an object.

**Edit:**

To fix this problem declare a ref variable to use in place of the array variable:

```
Array arr = Array.CreateInstance(System.Type.GetType("System.String"), 2);
arr.SetValue("1", 0);

object referenceObject = arr;

myfunction( ref referenceObject );
```

Comment: You asked why you were getting that problem... if you want to fix it then declare your array variable as an object.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the variable as object and not as array.
To populate the array with values you should keep your array variable and declare another one to give it to the method.

```
Array myArray = ....;
Object myObject = myArray;
myFunction(ref myObject);

// Update the original reference
myArray = myObject as Array;
```

Comment: how do I populate it with values then?